# Yama's worship mantra

Tags: mantras, worship, yama

As per [Skanda Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502118.html), Yama was cursed by a Brahmana known as Upādhyāya after his son's death that he'll not be worshipped. Later this curse was reduced that he'll be worshipped with non-vedic mantra.

> 51. As regards the curse uttered by me in regard to his worship earlier, O dear son, listen to what I say:
> 52. His worship with various kinds of Mantras mentioned in the Vedas will not find a place on the earth at all, dear son.
> 53. His worship shall be with Mantras composed by humans. It will be different from that of the other Devas. It is the truth that has been uttered by me.

Brahmana's son composed the mantra.

> 56. Then he composed the Mantra beginning with **“sugaṃ naḥ panthāḥ”** and performed the worship even as Dharmarāja was listening.

Please can someone help me with the full mantra mentioned here. Thanks.